# Multi-dimensional arrays and Pointers to those Arrays with one Typedef

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

This code works, allowing me to access 2D arrays through an array of pointers:

```
typedef uint8_t IMAGE_TYPE[4][8];
typedef uint8_t (*IMAGE_PTR_TYPE)[8];
IMAGE_TYPE test1 = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                    {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                    {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                    {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
IMAGE_TYPE test2 = {{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                    {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                    {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                    {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}};
IMAGE_PTR_TYPE test_ptr_array[] = {test1, test2};
```

It really annoys me that I have two typedefs, however.  It seems I should only need one, and that this code should work:

```
IMAGE_TYPE *test_ptr_array[] = {test1, test2};
```

It doesn't, however, giving me this error:

> error: cannot convert 'uint8_t (*)[8] {aka unsigned char (*)[8]}' to
>   'uint8_t (*)[4][8] {aka unsigned char (*)[4][8]}' in initialization

Does C have a way that I could handle this with only one typedef?

Comment: If you're willing to put up with an extra `*`, you could use `IMAGE_TYPE *ptr;` to declare your pointers.  But you'd then need to use `&` when assigning an `IMAGE_TYPE` to `ptr`, and to dereference you'd need the extra `*`, as in `(*ptr)[i][j]`.  Note sure if that's better, but it does address the specific complaint.

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers. It obfuscates your code and results eventually in confusion. What is you problem using array syntax for functions and elsewhere? It decays to a pointer anyway for most usages.

Comment: `IMAGE_TYPE *test_ptr_array[] = {&test1, &test2;}` should work.

Comment: @immibis - that does work!  Thanks!  I am used to not including & with arrays when I need their address that I didn't try it.

Comment: immibis and Tom's suggestion requires an extra deference when using the arrays via `test_ptr_array` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
typedef uint8_t ROW_TYPE[8];

ROW_TYPE test1[] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
                {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
ROW_TYPE test2[] = {{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
                {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}};

ROW_TYPE *test_ptr_array[] = {test1, test2};
```

Using this method, you would access numbers like `test_ptr_array[0][1][2]` which gives `test1[1][2]`.